# How do I properly provide auth token in header so that graphql does not redirect to login page?

Tags: javascript, authentication, graphql, k6

Within my QA org, I have been asked to build a JavaScript test file to call our graphQL endpoints using k6 (loadimpact). I am generating our auth token successfully and adding it to the header of the call I'm making.  But for some reason I'm being redirected to our company login page.  What is the proper way to make this call without the redirection?

I'm creating my header:

```
let headers = {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                "accept": "*/*",
                "Origin": "https://myurl.com",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36",
                "DNT": "1",
                "content-type": "application/json" };
```

My call to graphQL:

```
let myResponse = http.post("https://myurl.com/load/graphql", 
   "{..variables...query..}",
      {headers: headers});
```

And even though the auth code generated is valid, I'll receive a return result like:

```
{
  "remote_ip": "myIP",
  "remote_port": 443,
  "url": "https://companyURL/login/",
  "status": 200,
  "proto": "HTTP/1.1",
  "headers": {
    "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=0",
    "Last-Modified": "Wed, 18 Sep 2019 17:47:24 GMT",
    "Etag": "W/\"527-16d457c67e0\"",
    "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
    "Content-Length": "1319",
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Vary": "Origin",
    "X-Powered-By": "Express, ASP.NET",
    "Date": "Tue, 14 Jan 2020 15:13:05 GMT",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
  },
  "cookies": {},
  "body": "**...My company page login HTML...**",
  "timings": {
    "duration": 26.9992,
    "blocked": 0,
    "looking_up": 0,
    "connecting": 0,
    "tls_handshaking": 0,
    "sending": 0,
    "waiting": 26.9992,
    "receiving": 0
  },
  "tls_version": "tls1.2",
  "tls_cipher_suite": "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
  "ocsp": {
    "produced_at": 0,
    "this_update": 0,
    "next_update": 0,
    "revoked_at": 0,
    "revocation_reason": "",
    "status": "unknown"
  },
  "error": "",
  "error_code": 0,
  "request": {
"method": "POST",
"url": "https://myurl/load/graphql",
"headers": {
  "Origin": [
    "https://myurl"
  ],
  "Dnt": [
    "1"
  ],
  "Content-Type": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "User-Agent": [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"
  ],
  "Authorization": [
    "Bearer myreallylongauthcode"
  ],
  "Accept": [
    "*/*"
  ]
},
"body": "...env variables..query..",
"cookies": {}
```

}
}

I've reviewed the other questions relating to graphQL but nothing seems to quite fit.  When viewing the K6 documentation on the loadimpact site it shows adding the auth code to the header, but that clearly doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just passing `headers` as the third argument to `http.post()`, you should pass it like this: `http.post("https://myurl.com/load/graphql",  {..variables...query..}", {headers: headers});`

More examples here: https://docs.k6.io/docs/params-k6http

Comment: The response now contains the headers properly (thanks) but the result is still the same.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what else could be the reason. I suggest trying to run this request against an HTTP "mirror" like https://httpbin.org/anything, to make sure your request is precisely what you expect it to be. Also, try updating to the latest k6 version, v0.26.0 - IIRC there aren't weren't any bugs in the v0.25.0 version you're using that could be causing this, but it doesn't hurt to try updating to the latest version.